# Actualizar vista al seleccionar un ChekBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, vba

tengo el siguiente código y necesito que al seleccionar el **CheckBox** se habilite o des habilite el **DropDown**, eso debe pasar instantáneamente cada que se seleccione el **CheckBox1**, no se si exista una propiedad o como hacerlo.

```
<tr>
  <td align="right">
     <label for="direccionAnterior">Dirección Anterior</label>
  </td>
    <td align="left">
     <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text=" " runat="server" checked="true" TextAlign="Right" />
     <label>Conservar la direccion actual</label>
     <input name="direccionAnterior" readonly="true" type="text" class="textos" id="direccionAnterior" value="<%=cDireccionAnterior%>" size="56" maxlength="240" style="width:100%;"  title=""/>
    </td>
</tr>
  <tr> 
    <% If (CheckBox1.Checked) Then %> 
    <td align="right">
      <label for="direccion">* Dirección</label>
    </td>
    <td align="left">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DrdDireccion1" runat="server" onchange="modificado = true;">
    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">-Seleccione-</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Calle</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Carrera</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Avenida</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Av.Carrera</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Av.Calle</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Circular</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Circunvalar</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Diagonal</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Manzana</asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Transverzal </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem>Via</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList> 
   <%End If%>
 </tr>
```

Les agradezco de antemano por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías agregar ambos controles a **UpdatePanel** y en el evento **CheckedChanged** validar si esta chequeado o no y cambiar la propiedad **Enabled** del **DropDownList**

[asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net):

```
<form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net):

```
 Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            DropDownList1.Enabled = False
        Else
            DropDownList1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

no olvides habilitar al CheckBox la propiedad **AutoPostBack="true"**.

espero sea de ayuda